# How to do web scraping to extract product data(product name, price) from Lazada by using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, e-commerce, product, data-analysis

I have been told to scraping the product data(product name and price) from Lazada Website by using Python. However, I have no idea how to execute even after searching all the solution from internet. Does anyone could help me with this?

I have search all over the internet and Youtube just none of the coding could solve my problem.

The URL:
https://www.lazada.com.my/guardian/?q=All-Products&from=wangpu&langFlag=en&pageTypeId=2

I am using MacBook Air M1. I just have to extract all the product name and price from the shop (given by url) on all 102 pages.

Really hope someone could save me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't scrape the whole platform, it would be too complicated. Instead I would use their API. First you will need to register and get your app_key and app_secret. Then you can use their own library to communicate with the API called `lazop_sdk`. Details [here](https://open.lazada.com/apps/doc/doc?nodeId=10534&docId=108130)
Then you can start with this simple GET request

```py
from lazop_sdk import LazopClient, LazopRequest

# Set up the Lazop client with your app key and secret
app_key = 'your_app_key'
app_secret = 'your_app_secret'
client = LazopClient(app_key, app_secret)

# Set up the Lazop request to retrieve all products
request = LazopRequest('/products/get', 'GET')
request.add_api_param('offset', 0)
request.add_api_param('limit', 100)

# Send the request and retrieve the response
response = client.execute(request)

# Print the list of products
products = response['data']['products']
for product in products:
    print(product)
```